# Is there a way to get all errors from executeBatch?

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

Is there a way to get all errors from `executeBatch`?

I mean, if I am going to get 10 errors from a batch of 100, how can I know them all in the `executeBatch` execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error will throw an [`BatchUpdateException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/BatchUpdateException.html) that will stop the batch process.

You can see in the doc

> The subclass of `SQLException` thrown when an error occurs during a batch update operation. In addition to the information provided by `SQLException`, a `BatchUpdateException` provides the **update counts for all commands that were executed successfully during the batch update, that is, all commands that were executed before the error occurred**. The order of elements in an array of update counts corresponds to the order in which commands were added to the batch.

So the batch will stop there. Every previous "query" before the faulty one will be executed (in order). The rest would be ignored.

You can always recreate the batch since you have the successful execution count in the exception to contains the rest of the batch

EDIT :

The previous statement is partially wrong. The doc also states that the rest of the batch COULD be executed depending on the driver used

> After a command in a batch update fails to execute properly and a `BatchUpdateException` is thrown, **the driver may or may not continue** to process the remaining commands in the batch.

You can found the faulty statement (to test for confirmation)

> In the case where the driver continues processing commands, the array element for any command that failed is `Statement.EXECUTE_FAILED`.

Comment: do you have any reference for a driver which has this behavior? is it available for Oracle db?

Comment: @MozenRath You might want to read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/jdbcvers.htm#i1056887) corresponding, here some more [specific doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/oraperf.htm#i1058859) OR run some test, it is easy to create a batch on a test table with a simple unique constraint to create some error.

Comment: I have tested and know that the ojdbc driver does not have this support. It simply gives the first error. But I am curious to know if there is any specific driver that implements this strategy.

Comment: @mozenrath This is always possible so implements both possibility. Even Oracle can add it in the next version ;)

Comment: AFAIK MS SQL does this, Oracle doesn't, PostgreSQL definitely doesn't. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/performing-batch-operations?view=sql-server-2017 .